# How do you set given indices to $1$ in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have following lines of code to create a permutation matrix.

```
 R=zeros(N^2,N^2);
 R1=randperm(N^2);
 for j=1:N^2
     R(j,R1(j))=1;
 end
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: You can replace your loop with `R(1:N^2,R1)=1`

Comment: @BillBokeey, that will make a matrix with only ones. What you're saying is:  Give the value `1` to the entire column in column `R1(1)`, then give the value `1` to the entire column in column `R1(2)`, etc. Since `sort(R1) = 1:N^2`, this will be equivalent to `R(1:end,1:end) = R(:,:) = 1`.

Comment: Indeed, I should not answer before taking my first coffee of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [linear indexing](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) like this:

```
N = 3;
R = zeros(N^2);
R(randperm(N^2) + (0:N^2:(N^4-N^2))) = 1;
```

This works because the `N^2+1` is the first element in the second column, `2*N^2+4` is the fourth element in the third column etc.

Let's define `M = N^2` to make the explanation simpler. Now, `0:M:(M^2-M)` creates a matrix `[0 M 2*M 3*M ... (M-1)*M]`. By adding `R1` you will get a vector with elements `[R1(1), M+R1(2) 2*M+R1(3) ... (M-1)*M+R1(M)]`. If you use those numbers as indices, the first number will correspond to row `R1(1)` in the first column, the second number will correspond to the `R1(2)` in the second column etc.

Now you can assign the value `1` to the `R`-matrix in these positions. You might want to have a look at the function [`ind2sub`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to understand how this works. `ind2sub` converts the linear indices into the "normal" `[rows cols]` indexing style.

```
pos = randperm(M)+(0:M:(M^2-M))
pos =
     1    15    26    31    38    54    59    70    75
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(R), pos)
row =
     1     6     8     4     2     9     5     7     3
col =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

If you need the `R1` variable some other place, you can of course do:

```
R = zeros(N^2);
R1 = randperm(N^2)
R(R1 + (0:N^2:(N^4-N^2))) = 1;
```